# XCode 12 Unable To Build In Release Mode Using Sentry.io

Tags: react-native, sentry, xcode12

On XCode 12, I am trying to run a react native app using react-native 0.63.2 using @sentry/react-native": "^1.7.2".  If anyone has any ideas of what might be causing this, I have been trying to figure this out for days.  Thanks!

```
/Users/adamtoth-fejel/Documents/GitHub/testerapp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/loadMetroConfig.js:94
    ...options
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/adamtoth-fejel/Documents/GitHub/testerapp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/start/runServer.js:48:47)
+ [[ false != true ]]
+ [[ ! -f /Users/adamtoth-fejel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testerapp-ditgalwgipyeasbpogsaaqnsxcqe/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/testerapp.app/main.jsbundle ]]
error: EOF while parsing a value at line 1 column 0

Add --log-level=[info|debug] or export SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=[info|debug] to see more output.
Please attach the full debug log to all bug reports.
```

Comment: Any update on that? I'm having a similar issue